# C++ to .net dictionary, got MarshalDirectiveException

Tags: c#, c++, exception, dictionary

I have a cpp project (create test.DLL) and a C# win forms project (use  test.DLL). How can I convert C++ dictionary to .net dictonary?

I try this code but I got an `unhandled exception` of type `System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException`

**DLL cpp project**

```
Dictionary<int, int>^ TestDictionaryElements()
{
    Dictionary<int, int>^ h_result = gcnew Dictionary<int, int>();

    h_result->Add(1, 2);

    return (h_result);
}
extern "C"
{
     Dictionary<int, int>^ TestDic()
     {
         Dictionary<int, int>^ dic_result = TestDictionaryElements();
         return dic_result;
     }
}
```

**C# win forms project**

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("test.dll")]
    public static extern Dictionary<int, int> TestDic();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> resulDic = TestDic();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1810087 It's C++/CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in you cpp project you already use managed C++ (CLI) Therefore you don't have to export something. You can reference your managed c++ dll directly. Then you can call "TestDictionaryElements" directly. No DllImport is required.

To access your CLI code, you should create a public class which contains your code:

**CPP**

```
public ref class TestDictionary
{
public:

    Dictionary<int, int>^ TestDictionaryElements()
    {

        Dictionary<int, int>^ h_result = gcnew Dictionary<int, int>();

        h_result->Add(1, 2);

        return (h_result);
    }
}
```

**c#**

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestDictionary testDict = new TestDictionary();
        var result =testDict.TestDictionaryElements();
    }
 }
```

Comment: when I reference the managed c++ dll directly, I got error `A reference to test.dll couldn't not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component `

Comment: make dict public.  Only public object can be accessed.

Comment: You compiled your "test.dll" with Common language runtime support (/clr) right?

Comment: @Manuel. It's OK with your example code. Thank's for your help.